# CSS 3 gradient not working on chrome/firefox

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    *{padding:0;margin:0;}
    body{
        background: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            right bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0.25, #F5A432),
            color-stop(0.63, #F0F050)
        );
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(
            right bottom,
            #F5A432 25%,
            #F0F050 63%
        );
    }

    .box{margin-left: 33px; width:100px; height: 100px; background-color:rgb(69,69,69); border: 1px solid rgb(56,56,56);border-radius: 25px; float:left}
    #container{padding-left: 37%; padding-right: 30%; width: 1000px; background-color: rgb(64,64,64); position:fixed}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No gradient is showing in the code above! Just a plain white background. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only element inside `body` (`#container`) has `position: fixed`.

An element with `position: fixed` is removed from normal flow, so the `body` has no height.

You can "fix" this with:

```
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    min-height: 100%
}
```

**See:** http://jsbin.com/alucix

Comment: When I remove the position:fixed, the container disappears.

Comment: If you don't actually need `position: fixed`, then your question becomes ["how can I clear my floats?"](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59). And a simple solution to that is to remove `position: fixed` and add `overflow: hidden`, like this: http://jsbin.com/alucix/2. This is all a bit unclear, so guessing as best I can..

Comment: Yeah, with overflow: hidden it works well. Just one thing: The gradient should be diagonal, but it's appearing vertical.

Comment: It looks like you also need the snippet from my answer: http://jsbin.com/alucix/3

Comment: http://jsbin.com/alucix/4/ Any idea how to make the boxes @ the center of the container?

Comment: On `.box`, instead of `float: left`, use `display: inline-block`. Use `text-align: center` on the parent element to center the `inline-block` elements: http://jsbin.com/alucix/5. This is starting to veer off too far from the original question..

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code in Chrome (version 12.0.742.100) and it works as intended.

The Firefox code doesn't work and it's because of margin: 0; on body. The bug has been reported @ https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=509681.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox behave the same for me. Can you provide a JS Bin test case where Chrome and Firefox behave differently here?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/erayij

However. I noticed the code was missing the DOCTYPE. Once I put it in, chrome behaves just the same as Firefox. Weird.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. In Quirks Mode (no doctype), all bets (for consistency between browsers) are off. I added the doctype without mentioning it (oops) in the demos on my answer/comment.

Comment: If you close the doctype like <!DOCTYPE html> Chrome behaves like Firefox. If you do <!DOCTYPE html /> it works as intended in Chrome (still not working in Firefox though)